# Equivalent definition of finitely generated $A$- algebra, where $A$ is a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

***Def.*** The homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ is of finite type, and $B$ is a finitely- generated $A$-algebra, if there exists a finite set of elements $x_1.\dots, x_n$ in $B$ such that every element of $B$ can be written as a polynomial in $x_1,\dots, x_n$ with coefficients in $f(A)$; $\color{red}{or\; equivalently\;}$ if there is an $A$-algebra homomorphism from polynomial ring $A[t_1,\dots, t_n]$ onto $B$.

We suppose that every element of $B$ can be write as a polynomial in $x_1,\dots, x_n$ with coefficients in $f(A)$, then this means that the homomorphism $$g\colon A[t_1,\dots, t_n]\to B,\quad g(t_i)=x_i,\; g(a)=f(a)\;\text{for all}\; a\in A$$ is surjective.

Now, if we have a surjective homomorphism $A[t_1,\dots. t_n]\to B$, how can I conclude that every element of $B$ can be written as a polynomial in $x_1,\dots, x_n$?

Comment: Simply for each $i$, denote $x_i$ the image of $t_i$ in $B$.

Comment: @Bernard and as regards the coefficients, if we call homomorphism h, do these live in h (A)?

Comment: Yes, for a $A$-algebra homomorphism, $ h(a t_i^r)=a\bigl(h(t_i)\bigr)^r=a x_i^r$.